# Unit Test Using Forcing Authentication Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I'm building RESTful API services using django rest framework, I've reached the point where i have to create an automated test for my RESTful API services.

The sessionList api require token authentication, in case the user doesn't have the token he won't be able to access the session collection.

The api worked fine when I've tested it using POSTMAN and the real browser.

SessionList:

```
class SessionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    throttle_scope = 'session'
    throttle_classes = (ScopedRateThrottle,)

    name = 'session-list'

    filter_class = SessionFilter
    serializer_class = SessionSerializer
    ordering_fields = (
        'distance_in_miles',
        'speed'
    )

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Session.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Then i've created an automated test using DRF test

RunningSessionTest:

```
class RunningSessionTest(APITestCase):

    def test_get_sessions(self):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        view = views.SessionList.as_view()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            'user01', 'user01@example.com', 'user01P4ssw0rD')

        request = factory.get('http://localhost:8000/sessions/')
        force_authenticate(request, user=user)
        response = view(request)
        assert Response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK

    def test_get_sessions_not_authenticated_user(self):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        view = views.SessionList.as_view()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            'user01', 'user01@example.com', 'user01P4ssw0rD')

        request = factory.get('http://localhost:8000/sessions/')
        response = view(request)
        assert Response.status_code == status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
```

The issue: in both cases, if the user has the token or not the response value is HTTP_200_OK

I've tried to solve the problem by trying different methods to implement the test. I've used APIRequestFactory, Also i've used the  APIClient but i got the same result. To be honest after reading the document many times i couldn't understand the differences between the APIClient and the APIRequestFactory.

The result of the test :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python_work\DjnagoREST\01\restful01\RunKeeper\tests.py", line 67, in test_get_sessions_not_authenticated_user
    assert Response.status_code == status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
AssertionError
```

I will be grateful to your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you will need to change `Response.status_code` to `response.status_code`.

As it turned out Response.status_code (as from rest_framework.response.Response) 
is equal to 200 :D